# How can I set cookie when other website redirect to magento website

Tags: session, cookie, reward-points

Magento 2 website is mydoamin.com. (Refer a friend) External Website link redirect to my website. This will provide a reward based on refer a friend anyone buy product in Magento website.
After external website reachs Magento home page url
mydoamin.com/?aid=arabf7d00bddc712c3e51f5b44e6813bbeb1be803a0ff0d69b31c9e014c2a9da9e

This "aid" is name always static name and "arabf7d00bddc712c3e51f5b44e6813bbeb1be803a0ff0d69b31c9e014c2a9da9e" is dynamic change depends on links

I want to store this link name and value after Checkout success page phtml page get to call name and value check exist or not

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should use the event:

```
<event name="controller_front_send_response_before">
    <observer name="Observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Observer" shared="false" />
</event>
```

The observer:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Vendor\Module\Cookie\Aid;

class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $request;
    protected $cookie;

    public function __construct(
        Http $request,
        Aid $cookie,
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->cookie = $cookie;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->request->getParams(); // all params
        $param = $this->request->getParam('aid');

        $cookieExists = $this->cookie->get();
        if($param != "" && !$cookieExists){
            $this->cookie->set($param, 86400);
        }
    }
}
```

i've created a separated class for the Cookie in Vendor\Module\Cookie\Aid

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Cookie;

use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;

class Aid
{
    /**
     * Name of cookie that holds private content version
     */
    const COOKIE_NAME = 'aid';

    /**
     * CookieManager
     *
     * @var CookieManagerInterface
     */
    private $cookieManager;

    /**
     * @var CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private $cookieMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @var SessionManagerInterface
     */
    private $sessionManager;

    /**
     * @param CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
     * @param CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory
     * @param SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
        SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager,

    ) {
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
        $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager;
    }

    /**
     * Get form key cookie
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get()
    {
        return $this->cookieManager->getCookie(self::COOKIE_NAME);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $value
     * @param int $duration
     * @return void
     */
    public function set($value, $duration = 86400)
    {
        $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory
            ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
            ->setDuration($duration)
            ->setPath($this->sessionManager->getCookiePath())
            ->setDomain($this->sessionManager->getCookieDomain());

        $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
            self::COOKIE_NAME,
            $value,
            $metadata
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function delete()
    {
        $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory
            ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
            ->setDuration(36000)
            ->setPath($this->sessionManager->getCookiePath())
            ->setDomain($this->sessionManager->getCookieDomain());

        $this->cookieManager->deleteCookie(
            self::COOKIE_NAME,
            $metadata
        );
    }
}
```

With all of this you'll be able to use the cookie in your success page using the event "checkout_submit_all_after" if you need to send a curl or check if there's your cookie, or just updating the layout: checkout_onepage_success.xml adding your PHTML to the page

Comment: Thanks for you useful  answer, I got this error, 2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Mytask\ReferCookie\Observer\Aid does not exist

Comment: check that the di.xml observer event declaration of instance: Vendor\Module\Observer\Observer (if you called it Vendor\Module\Observer\Aid) be sure that it corresponds with the observer class

Comment: Can you please add example of di.xml in your answer?

Comment: i didn't need a di in my module, i just built a \Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\events.xml where i placed this code: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_front_send_response_before">
        <observer name="Observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Observer" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>

Comment: Have you ended up solving your issue?